# Modifying a variable with onvalue and offvalue

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to modify a variable with the checkbox widget elements onvalue and offvalue. I'm trying to add one to the current value of the variable when the user selects the checkbox on and minus one to the current value of the variable when the user deselects the checkbox.

Here's my code and the current error I'm getting:

```
from Tkinter import *
the_window = Tk()
boxticks = IntVar()
alpha_check = Checkbutton(the_window, text = 'Alpha', variable = boxticks,
                          onvalue = boxticks + 1, offvalue = boxticks - 1,
                          command = oddoreven)
```

> File "C:\Users\Chris\Downloads\checkbox_counter_Q.py", line 54, in 
>       onvalue = boxticks + 1, offvalue = boxticks - 1,
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'int'

What am I doing wrong? The desired outcome would be to have the boxticks variable being boosted by 1 when selected, and subtracted by 1 when deselected.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In line 3 try:

```
boxticks = IntVar().get()
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I knew it'd be something simple haha.

Comment: But if `boxticks` is now an integer, how can you get the value of the checkbox? You can't call `get` on an int, and it's immutable anyway.